# How to read an excel column into a list?

Tags: python, excel, string, unicode, xlrd

I'm reading a column from the Excel like this:

```
import xlrd
import openpyxl
book = xlrd.open_workbook("English corpus.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

data=[]
for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): # skip heading row
    timestamp, text, header, transporter, device_type = sheet.row_values(row_index,
                                                                         end_colx=5)
    print (text)
    data.append(text)
```

And then appending the cells from the `text` column (`text` column is a huge column having about 10000 entries) in the `data` list. But by doing this way, data is being appended in Unicode type format. And I'm unable to convert it to string (getting UnicodeEncode error - tried everything).

Could anyone please tell me of any other way to read the cells from an Excel column into a python list such that the list element are of time string only and not Unicode?

Comment: https://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2014/06/16/reading-excel-with-python-xlrd/

Comment: What version of Python?  Is your question actually *How do I convert a Unicode String to ascii?*

Comment: No, I need another way to add the excel cells into a list such that their type is not unicode in the first place

Comment: @wwii Check above comment please thanks.

Comment: I'm no expert but I'm pretty sure Excel works with Unicode text so if you are reading .xls (or .xlsx) files it will be Unicode.  If you want it to be something different you will need to convert it.

Comment: http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unicode.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

If you perfer `openpyxl` / `xlrd` you can try encoding data to `unicode`.
e.g.

```
s = u'about'
>>> s
u'about'
>>> s.encode("utf8")
'about'
>>>
```

for a list of data, you can use list comprehension as

```
data = [s.encode("utf8") for s in data]
```

And for easier import of excel columns to list  You can try `pandas` to load the `xls` data into a `pandas` `dataframe` and then send the `dataframe` to a `list`.

This will be more efficient as `pandas` is able to handle huge amount of data and its relatively easier to manipulate.

Conversion between strings / `Unicode` etc are also handled at the pandas level.

Here is an example.

```
file_name = 'words.xlsx'
import pandas as pd
xl_workbook = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)  # Load the excel workbook
df = xl_workbook.parse("Sheet1")  # Parse the sheet into a dataframe
aList = df['names'].tolist()  # Cast the desired column into a python list
```

So while `print aList` will show as unicode data.

```
   >>> print aList
    [u'ability (noun)', u'able (adjective)', u'about (preposition)', u'about (adverb)', u'above (adverb)', u'above (preposition)']
```

you can use  list comprehension to convert data to `string`.

```
>>> [str(i) for i in aList]
['ability (noun)', 'able (adjective)', 'about (preposition)', 'about (adverb)', 'above (adverb)', 'above (preposition)']
```